# mousenter mouseleave only affect one card at a time

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page with numerous Bootstrap Cards on it with an image of a person in the card. I'd like to hover the WHOLE card and have the image go from black and white to color.

I used css grey scale and hover which works fine but only when hovering on the image and not the card body. I figured I would try jquery and do a mouseenter mouseleave function which works to some degree. The problem is when I hover one card body EVERY image on the page goes from black and white to color, which makes sense given the all share the same class. I just wanrt whichever card is hovered to change to color.

HTML:

```
<div class="card mt-6 shadow filter sales-filt w-25">
  <div class="">
    <img src="images/alecPeople.png" class="card-img" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h6 class="card-title mb-0 text-uppercase">Alec Koyer</h6>
    <p class="card-text mb-3 people-p text-green fw-bold">Sales</p>
    <button class="js-video-button btn-people--launch" data-video-id='333' data-channel="vimeo"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.card-body').on('mouseover mouseout',function(){
  $('.card-img').toggleClass('card-img-hover')
});
```

hover card body section, image turns color but only card body that is hovered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference the card image element relative to the one that was hovered. By using `this` as a context for selecting the element, you are targeting only the one inside the hovered card.

```
$('.card-body').on('mouseover mouseout',function(){
  var cardImg = $(this).find('.card-img');
  cardImg.toggleClass('card-img-hover');
});
```

This did not work but it pointed me in the correct direction, much appreciated! :) I ended up having to select the WHOLE card element rather than just the card body:

```
$('.card').on('mouseover mouseout',function(){
    var cardImg = $(this).find('.card-img');
    cardImg.toggleClass('card-img-hover');
  });
```